# How can I add an object into a set in Java?

Tags: java, object, testing, junit

I am writing some JUnit tests for a bus stop but I am having trouble trying to create objects to be used through the tests:

```
public class StopTests {
  BusRoute rte = new BusRoute("250");
  Set<BusRoute> set = new Set<BusRoute>();
  BusStop stop = new BusStop(00000, "Staples Center", 90.0, 90.0, set);
...
}
```

My problem is that the test won't compile because Eclipse says "new Set()" cannot be instantiated. My intention is to add 'rte' into 'set' so that 'stop' can be created without compilation errors, but I am stumped on how to do this. I tried approaching it like:

```
public class StopTests {
  BusRoute rte = new BusRoute("250");
  Set<BusRoute> set = new Set<BusRoute>();
  set.add(BusRoute rte);
  BusStop stop = new BusStop(00000, "Staples Center", 90.0, 90.0, set);
...
}
```

but Eclipse gave me another error about not having an identifier following 'add'.

What would be the best way to approach this?

EDIT: This is what I have now:

```
public class StopTests {
  BusRoute rte = new BusRoute("250");
  Set<BusRoute> set = new HashSet<BusRoute>();
  set.add(rte);
  BusStop stop = new BusStop(00000, "Staples Center", 90.0, 90.0, set);
...
}
```

Comment: What do you think this notation `rts.add(BusRoute rte);` does?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis From reading the Java API it says that it adds an element into a set if it is not already in there.

Comment: What does the `BusRoute rte` notation do as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is an interface so cannot create an instance of it. You need to create and instance of Set implementations such as `HashSet`.

Try changing this:

```
Set<BusRoute> set = new Set<BusRoute>()
```

to

```
Set<BusRoute> set = new HashSet<BusRoute>()
```

Also to add the element in set you need to call `add` on set instance and not on `BusRoute` instance. So change this :

```
  rts.add(BusRoute rte);
```

to

```
  set.add(rte);
```

Comment: Combine that with @jmduke's answer and you have a winner ;-)

Comment: I have done that change but Java still gives me a compilation error for 
`code`set.add(BusRoute rte)

I understand what changing it to a HashSet has done, but I am still not sure how to add rte into the HashSet at this point.

Comment: @tigfra check my edit about adding the element in set.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I have made the changes but Eclipse is still giving me errors. The API says that for HashSet, .add requires two parameters (.add(E e)), why should BusRoute be removed from .add then?

Comment: @tigfra That's just one parameter.  I suggest spending some time learning to use these API documents.

Comment: @tigfra Set add method only requires one parameter: boolean add(E e)
Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. E is the type of parameter and e is the actual argument.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Ah alright, thank you for the insight. Sorry for my inexperience but we were not really taught how to use sets or anything of the sort.

I am still getting an error at this point though. Specifically, the error is "Syntax Error on token rte, VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token." Any idea on how to remedy this?

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I have right now. I am just very lost on where all these errors keep arising from.

Comment: @tigfra most likely that error has to do something with your BusRoute instance creation, check for number of parameters in your BusRoute constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is with this line: `rts.add(BusRoute rte)`.  You don't need to prepend `rte` with its type: use `rts.add(rte)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is an interface, you need to instantiate with an implementation class:

`Set<BusRoute> set = new HashSet<BusRoute>()`

Please see these links

[Set examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

[Set API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is abstract so it cannot be instantiated. You need to use an implementation of `Set`, such as `HashSet`.

```
public class StopTests {

    public void someMethod() {
        BusRoute rte = new BusRoute("250");
        Set<BusRoute> set = new HashSet<BusRoute>();
        set.add(rte);
        BusStop stop = new BusStop(00000, "Staples Center", 90.0, 90.0, set);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I did but I am now getting an error on the "set.add(rte)" line.

Eclipse is telling me "Syntax error on token rte, VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token."

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: You cannot execute code directly inside the class body. It must exist inside a method or in a static block. I edited my answer.